# Why IPv6 use colon as delimiter instead of dot?

Tags: ipv6

I cannot find the reason why IPv6 use colon as delimiter instead of dot.
When address is described with port number, it seems clumsy to me.

```
[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:443
```

What justify using colon?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I looked through the [older IPv6 RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1884) in order to find a clue about the history, but I think the answer lies in [RFC 4291 section 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2):

```
3. An alternative form that is sometimes more convenient when dealing
   with a mixed environment of IPv4 and IPv6 nodes is
   x:x:x:x:x:x:d.d.d.d, where the 'x's are the hexadecimal values of
   the six high-order 16-bit pieces of the address, and the 'd's are
   the decimal values of the four low-order 8-bit pieces of the
   address (standard IPv4 representation).  Examples:

      0:0:0:0:0:0:13.1.68.3

      0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.144.52.38

   or in compressed form:

      ::13.1.68.3
```

That is, you wouldn't be able "embed" an IPv4-compatible address if IPv6 addresses were dot-delimited.

To address your implication about the colon clashing with a port number in a URL, I think the answer is that at the time that [IPv6 was being designed in the early 1990s](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1550), [hypertext](http://www.kevcom.com/words/ht93/hypertext.faq.txt) and the [URL were being designed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) at the same time. Since port numbers are separate from IP addresses, there was no standard for specifying a *(port, address)* tuple. (The command-line `telnet` client, for example, uses a space to separate the IP address from the port.)

Comment: This is a good answer, but could you clarify the timeline here? RFC1550 doesn't mention the address format, and 1884 which does is newer than 1738 which uses "host:port". Was it in wide use before 1884?

Comment: @Thomas, I don't have exact timelines, but you can infer from the dates of the documents that the people working on IPv6 were not necessarily considering the hypertext use case. The web didn't become popular until many years after 1993. Conversely, I think it's clear that IPv6 address formats inside a URL were an afterthought. I think the two groups were developing those standards separately, and if they had coordinated, the outcome may have been different.

Comment: Yes, but IPV6 adoption was still miniscule, they could have changed things around when the address:port became so prevalent. They could have used underscores, or dashes, or tildes, or use a special wrapping chars for the ipv4-in-v6 specialty syntax. 

Seriously, why not underscores or dashes? UUIDs use dashes everywhere with a fair amount of impunity.

Comment: @ConstanceEustace, yeah, I always thought using `-` would be much better so you would't need to use the shift key, and you'd have the benefit of that key being on the numeric keypad. But no such luck.